# how to add multiple values to single key in java

Tags: java

How can I create a map that can extend its list of value. For example I have a map which contains: key A and list of values B {1,2,3}. Then at some point during the program running, I would like to add more value, ex: 4 to list B. Now my new map should be something like: (A,{1,2,3,4}). How can I do that?

Comment: `map.get("A").add(4);`

Comment: @QBrute this won't work as when you print the map it just prints the latest entry which in your case is 4, but not 1,2,3,4 like the questions asks.

Comment: @war_Hero that doesn't make sense, have you *tried* it? Of course you get the map with the complete list and not just the latest entry when you print it.

Comment: Lol, dude read the docs or even refer to answer below, they are using a list to store the values, as for a map it's only one key one value, it's a common gotcha unless you have tired it in code,  wanted to call it out as it should not mislead others.

Comment: If you have a container like `Map` that holds a reference to a `List` and then you fetch that list and change it around then that change will be visible in the map. You don't *replace* the value of the map, you *update* it. **That list is the value**. If you have a map `{A=[1, 2, 3]}` and then you do `map.get("A")` you hold the reference to the list `[1,2,3]`. Then you do `.add(4)` on that same list. If you print out the map afterwards you will see `{A=[1, 2, 3, 4]}` because you're working with references! Please get your facts straight before calling me out on a completely wrong basis.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `Map<K,V>` maps one key to one value, you need `V` to be of type `List<T>`:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> multiMap = new HashMap<>();
```

One consequence of having a type like that is that now the process of adding an item to a key consists of two steps: you must check if the list for the key exists, and then either add a new item to an existing list, or add a new list with a single item:

```
List<Integer> current = multiMap.get(key);
if (current == null) {
    current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    multiMap.put(key, current);
}
current.add(val);
```

If you use Java 8, you can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to greatly simplify the code:

```
multiMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```

Comment: You can simplify the implementation by using the newer `computeIfAbsent` method: `multiMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);`

Comment: @MalteHartwig Right, Java 8 added this convenient option, which greatly improves readability of the operation. Thank you!

Comment: @MalteHartwig: wow thank you! this look great and more professional with Java 8!

Answer (score 3):

Such type of collection already implemented. Take a look at [Multimap from Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap). Don't invent the bike from the scratch.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Add new Integer using new temp variable, 
Check with this explains might be help.

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    map.put("A", list);
    map.forEach((key,value)->System.out.print(key + " : "+
    value));
    List<Integer> newList = (ArrayList<Integer>)map.get("A");
    newList.add(4);
    System.out.println();
    map.put("A", newList);
    map.forEach((key,value)->System.out.print(key + " : "+
            value));
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution is to have a MultiMap class which
provides any Collection type as value e.g. ArrayList:
I found this in a Java-Book weeks ago. Example:

```
class MultiMap<K, V> 
{
  private final Map<K,Collection<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

  public Collection<V> get(K key) 
  {
    return map.getOrDefault(key, Collections.<V> emptyList());
  }
  public void put(K key,V value )
  {
    map.computeIfAbsent( key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add( value );
  }
}
```

Usage may be: (the map value is a ArrayList of Strings)

```
MultiMap<Integer,String> map = new MultiMap<>();
int id = 34;
System.out.println(map.get(id)); // creates an ArrayList<String> for key 34

map.put(id,"first value for 34");
System.out.println(map.get(id)); // [first value for 34]

map.put(id,"second");
System.out.println(map.get(id)); // [first value for 34, second]
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
valSetOne.add("ABC");
valSetOne.add("BCD");
valSetOne.add("DEF");

List<String> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
valSetTwo.add("CBA");
valSetTwo.add("DCB");

map.put("FirstKey", valSetOne);
map.put("SecondKey", valSetTwo);

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

    String key = entry.getKey();

    List<String> values = entry.getValue();

    System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is " + values);

}
```

}

You can use Set or List based on your requirement.This is a simple method of having single key with multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

> Java 8. Stream API.

For example we have collection of Users as List:

```
[{ name: "qwer", surname: "asdf", type: "premium"}, { name: "ioup", surname: "vmnv", type: "usual"}, { name: "rtyr", surname: "zxc", type: "premium"}]
```

and we need to add multiple Users to Map where key is «type»

```
Map<String, List<User>> map = collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getType, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())))
```

To process this map we can make new stream

```
map.entrySet().stream().{map|reduce|& other things}...
```